# Where is wpa-conf documented?

Tags: network-interface, documentation, wlan

I use `wpa-conf` in `/etc/network/interfaces` to make the WLAN interface automatically connect to the AP:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Actually, I just found that on a wiki somewhere. It seems that this isn't documented in interfaces(5) or in *any* other man page.

So what *is* the `wpa-conf` keyword? A kind of extension? Or is it built into `ifup`? And where do I get a list of all the commands I can use in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Is it a function  in one of the  /etc/network/interfaces.d/* files?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: `wpa-conf` is not in my `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`.

Comment: It's documented (on Debian) in /usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.modes.gz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for `/etc/network/interfaces`, when you install `wpa-supplicant`, a script hook is installed in:

- `/etc/network/if-down.d`
- `/etc/network/if-post-down.d`
- `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`
- `/etc/network/if-up.d`,

The hook is called `wpasupplicant` and is a symlink to `/etc/wpa-supplicant/ifupdown.sh`, that invokes in turn `/etc/wpa-supplicant/functions.sh`.

This hook will be invoked by `runparts` in `ifup` / `ifdown`, and the script the symlink points too tests whether the interface is wireless or not. If that is the case, the command will be passed on to `wpa-supplicant`.

For acting on the commands, passing them to `/sbin/wpa-supplicant`, it seems the script `/sbin/wpa_action` and the binary `/sbin/wpa_cli` are used.

I found an old page talking about this here:

http://manual.siduction.org/inet-wpa

> As mentioned earlier, each wpa_supplicant specific element is prefixed
>   with 'wpa-'. Each element correlates to a property of wpa_supplicant
>   described in the wpa_supplicant.conf(5), wpa_supplicant(8) and
>   wpa_cli(8) manpages.
>
> The supplicant is launched without any pre-configuration whatsoever,
>   and wpa_cli forms a network configuration from the input provided by
>   the 'wpa-*' lines. Initially, wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli does not directly
>   set the properties of the device (like setting an essid with iwconfig,
>   for example), rather it informs the device of what access point is
>   suitable to associate with. Once the device has scanned the area, and
>   found that the suitable access point is available for use, these
>   properties are set.
>
> The script that does all the work is located at:
>
> /etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh
>   ifupdown.sh is executed by run-parts, which in turn is invoked by
>   ifupdown during the 'pre-up', 'pre-down' and 'post-down' phases.
>
> In the 'pre-up' phase, a wpa_supplicant daemon is launched followed by
>   a series of wpa_cli commands that set up a network configuration
>   according to what 'wpa-' options were used in /etc/network/interfaces
>   for the physical device.
>
> If wpa-roam is used, a wpa_cli daemon is lauched in the 'post-up'
>   phase.
>
> In the 'pre-down' phase, the wpa_cli daemon is killed if it exists.
>
> In the 'post-down' phase, the wpa_supplicant daemon is killed.

Comment: Why isn't it indented like other options associated with an interface? If there are multiple such lines will they interfere?

Comment: @detly If you have questions about the subject, please open a new question.